# Update field value based on file extension

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Table having 2 fields

`FileName` and `FileType`

```
 FileName         FileType

File1.txt           png

File2.png           docx

File3.docx          txt
```

I want to update the `FileType` fields based on the corresponding file extensions in `FileName` field

Comment: If `FileName` is `File1.txt` means, then in `FileType`, it shoul be `txt` and not `png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, even in cases where there is no file extension in `FileName`:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET FileType = NULLIF(SUBSTRING(FileName, LEN(FileName) - 
CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(FileName)) + 2, LEN(FileName)), '')
```

Basically it sets the `FileType` value to a substring pulled from the `FileName` field starting right after the last index of the `.` character.  If there is no file extension in `FileName`, e.g. `File4`, it will set `FileType` to `NULL`.